# How do I use jQuery to find image (there are many generated <tr>'s in succession) by the end value of its ID?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am attempting to have <tr>'s be created "for each object" when pulled from the database, this much works great.

**What I can't seem to get right:**

my image id's are inserted using jQuery, the <tr> they are within being created when User submits form request. (rowID happens to be the 'Object ID' in the "for each object" part of the jQuery/Ajax).

```
 <img id="' + rowID + '_rowImage" class="rowImage" src="img/no.png" />
```

and I wish to have jQuery cause this image to be clicked with an alert (once the alert works, I'll be taking the -actual- scripting from here).

I've tried to use this, as I've found here within StackExchange:

```
            $("element[id$='_rowImage']").on('click', function () {
               alert("hi");
            });
```

Also trying this:

```
            $("img[id$='_rowImage']").on('click', function () {
               alert("hi");
            });
```

And also this:

```
            $("[id$='_rowImage']").on('click', function () {
               alert("hi");
            });
```

.... and none of them work.
Does anyone have an idea as to why this won't click to alert me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: How is `rowID` added at `id` attribute? Is actual `html` `<img id="' + rowID + '_rowImage" class="rowImage" src="img/no.png" />`? Can you include portion of `php` or `javascript` where `id` is created at Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .on() method to attach event handlers to dynamically generated elements.

```
$("body").on('click', '.rowImage', function(){
    alert("You click: " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: I prefer using .on() for sure, thank you. 
I've tried using this, and still no 'alert'.
(image class name is actually "requestPaidImage", this is a copy/paste from my code):

            $("body").on('click', 'requestPaidImage', function(){
                alert("hi");
             });

do you know why this isn't working?

Comment: You missed a dot "." before your class name
`$("body").on('click', '.requestPaidImage', function(){ alert("hi"); });`

Answer (score 0):

Making it more difficult than needed when you can simply use the class

```
$('.rowImage').click...
```

Comment: $().click is depreciated at this point; $().on() is what's -in-

Comment: @MekLeN cite reference for it being deprecated. Not documented and has been in library for 10 years